# Push view-controller twice

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have 3 view controllers with 2 buttons each one.

First view:

1. Next (Go to the 2 view controller)
2. End (Go to the 3 view controller)

Second view:

1. Back (Go to the 1 view controller)
2. End (Go to the 3 view controller)

Third view:

1. Back (Go to the 2 view controller)
2. Start (Go to the 1 view controller)

The problem is the "back" button of the third view controller do:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

So when I come from the second view, there is no problem, I return to the second view, but when I come from the first view and I press the back button, the app returns to the first view controller, and I want to navigate to the second view.

Is there any way to push 2 view controller when I press the "End" button in the first view controller, so when I press back button in the third view controller its returns to the second?

Thanks!

Comment: how are you navigating? with performSegueWithIdentifier?

Comment: on back of 3rd controller you have to check if there is 2nd controller is in stack or not if it is then simple pop otherwise push 2nd controller.

Comment: Basically speaking, what OP is about to do is kinda bad practice. Why having a navigationController in first place, when he wants to navigate in all directions? normally, navigation would be 1-2-3, and then 3-2-1, and not 2-1-3 or sth else

Comment: How can I check it the 2nd controller is in stack? and if it isn't how can I add to the stack?

Comment: For example you have only one controller in a stack, 2-th (just assume).
So put manually 3-th before 2-th, and made pop

Answer (score 2):

You can push multiple view controllers by executing `navigationController.pushViewController(viewControllerN, animated: false)` multiple times and set `animated` only for the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Simple you can push multiple controller by instantiate story board as mentioned in another answer.

Another way is (in objective c - covert it in swift!!),

```
 NSMutableArray *controllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
 [controllers addObject:secondVc];
 [controllers addObject:thirdVC];
 [self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
```

By calling `self.navigationController.viewControllers` we get array of navigation stack. we can add or remove object from this array and final;y can set this array to navigationcontroller by `[self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];`

By this way you can manage your view hierarchy like if you want to push three view controller then you can easily do or if you want to push first and third on first then add this object to array likewise if you remove particular view then remove that object from array.

According to your need as per question this kind of approach is more appropriate i think.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can push two view controller following way. Make sure that animated: false so user can not identify there are push two view controller.

```
 let ObjVC1 = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryBoardID") as! Profile
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ObjVC1, animated: false)


 let ObjVC2 = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryBoardID") as! Profile
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ObjVC2, animated: true)
```

Comment: Perfect! It solve my problem. But now I have other. When I push the first time I see for a second the 2nd view. There is any way to don't see the second view, like I navigate only to the third view?